# How to create Grid View using JQuery

Tags: jquery, gridview

Can u Please help me how to create grid view using JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of good plugins namely [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/).

Lots of examples and demos available at the above two links.